# how to use variable as object in json (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
var text = '{ "nusers" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"sadsf" , "lastName":"sdasda" },' +
'{ "firstName":"fnSaleh" , "lastName":"lnSaleh" }]}';

var va = "nuser";
 obj = JSON.parse(text);

for(i=0;i< (obj.va.length);i++){

var st = obj.va.firstName;

console.log(st);
}
```

Error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: it should be `obj[va].length`. That still won't work because there's a typo in `va`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems.

For starters use `[]` notation for variable property names. Then fix value of `va` to match the object property `nusers` not `nuser`. Finally, use index `i` to access the array elements within the loop

```js
var text = '{ "nusers" : [' +
  '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"sadsf" , "lastName":"sdasda" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"fnSaleh" , "lastName":"lnSaleh" }]}';

var va = "nusers";
obj = JSON.parse(text);

for (i = 0; i < (obj[va].length); i++) {

  var st = obj[va][i].firstName;

  console.log(st);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket when accessing an object property using a variable. Also you need to get the `index` so `obj[va][i].firstName` will give the first name

```js
var text = '{ "nusers" : [' +
  '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"sadsf" , "lastName":"sdasda" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"fnSaleh" , "lastName":"lnSaleh" }]}';

var va = "nusers";
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
for (var i = 0; i < (obj[va].length); i++) {
  var st = obj[va][i].firstName;
  console.log(st);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, declare all variabes on top.

Then use the right key (`'nusers'` with `s` at the end) for accessing the object.

For accessing an object, you need a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) which is here with bracket notation, because you have a variable. This is also necessary for accessing an array with an index.

```js
var text = '{ "nusers" : [' +
    '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"sadsf" , "lastName":"sdasda" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"fnSaleh" , "lastName":"lnSaleh" }]}',
    va = "nusers",
    obj = JSON.parse(text),
    i,
    st;

for (i = 0; i < obj[va].length; i++) {
    st = obj[va][i].firstName;
    console.log(st);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are several problems in your code.

1. va = 'nuser'  --> This need to be `nusers`
2. You should use `[]` notation for accessing property whenever you're using a variable to access the property.
3. In the loop you need to use index too to access the first name.

```js
var text = '{ "nusers" : [' +'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +'{ "firstName":"sadsf" , "lastName":"sdasda" },' +'{ "firstName":"fnSaleh" , "lastName":"lnSaleh" }]}';

var va = "nusers";  
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

for(i=0; i< obj[va].length; i++){
  var st = obj[va][i].firstName;
  console.log(st);
}
```